# Grouping from a CTE which is within a CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a CTE like so -

```
with cte (
    org1, org2, org3
    , ind1, ind2, ind3
  ) as (
    -- a bunch of queries
    ) 
  SELECT 
    org1 as org, 
    ind2 as ind, 
    count(*) as count_final 
  from 
    cte 
  group by 
    org1, 
    ind2 
  union all 
  SELECT 
    org1 as org, 
    ind3 as ind, 
    count(*) as count_final 
  from 
    cte 
  group by 
    org1, 
    ind3 
  union all 
  SELECT 
    org2 as org, 
    ind1 as ind, 
    count(*) as count_final 
  from 
    cte 
  group by 
    org2, 
    ind1 
  union all 
  SELECT 
    org2 as org, 
    ind3 as ind, 
    count(*) as count_final 
  from 
    cte 
  group by 
    org2, 
    ind3 
  union all 
  SELECT 
    org3 as org, 
    ind1 as ind, 
    count(*) as count_final 
  from 
    cte 
  group by 
    org3, 
    ind1 
  union all 
  SELECT 
    org3 as org, 
    ind2 as ind, 
    count(*) as count_final 
  from 
    cte 
  group by 
    org3, 
    ind2;
```

Once I have org, ind and count_final, how do I do this -

```
select org, ind, sum(count_final) as count from cte_final
group by org, ind
```

I tried to create another cte on top of this one so I could run this query but I am getting an error stating that there is an ambiguous reference to `org`. This is what I have tried -

```
with cte_final (org, ind)
as (
with cte (org1, org2, org3, ind1, ind2, ind3)
as (

--a bunch of queries

    )

SELECT org1 as org , ind2 as ind, count(*) as count_final from cte
group by org1 , ind2 
union all
SELECT org1 as org , ind3 as ind, count(*) as count_final from cte
group by org1 , ind3 
union all
SELECT org2 as org , ind1 as ind, count(*) as count_final from cte
group by org2 , ind1
union all
SELECT org2 as org , ind3 as ind, count(*) as count_final from cte
group by org2 , ind3
union all
SELECT org3 as org , ind1 as ind, count(*) as count_final from cte
group by org3 , ind1
union all
SELECT org3 as org , ind2 as ind, count(*) as count_final from cte
group by org3 , ind2
;
)
select org, ind, sum(count_final) as count from cte_final
group by org, ind;
```

Input -

```
Org             Ind             Count_Final
"1023043221"    "156832423986"  "17"
"1023043221"    "156832423986"  "1"
"14325495102"   "142722349564"  "1"
```

I want this result -

```
Org             Ind             Count_Final
"1023043221"    "156832423986"  "18"
"14325495102"   "142722349564"  "1"
```

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do, first with words, then with sample data and desired results, and finally, you can show your attempts at code.  You have not explained what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: If you just go with your code, I think you just need to replace `with cte_final (org, ind)` to `with cte_final (org, ind, final_count)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need one cte. Try:

```
WITH cte
AS (

--bunch of queries

    )
SELECT org
    , ind
    , sum(count_final) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT org1 AS org
        , ind2 AS ind
        , count(*) AS count_final
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY org1
        , ind2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT org1 AS org
        , ind3 AS ind
        , count(*) AS count_final
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY org1
        , ind3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT org2 AS org
        , ind1 AS ind
        , count(*) AS count_final
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY org2
        , ind1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT org2 AS org
        , ind3 AS ind
        , count(*) AS count_final
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY org2
        , ind3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT org3 AS org
        , ind1 AS ind
        , count(*) AS count_final
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY org3
        , ind1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT org3 AS org
        , ind2 AS ind
        , count(*) AS count_final
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY org3
        , ind2
    ) x
GROUP BY org
    , ind;
```